# Xcode build rules script "command not found" on M1

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have a project that runs some utility I've installed using homebrew on one of its build rules.

On my M1 mac, homebrew is installed on `/opt/homebrew/bin`.

I have `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` present in my `~/.zprofile` file, but it seems like Xcode doesn't respect that (or maybe overrides it?).

When trying to evaluate the `PATH` variable during Xcode run script command I get the following:

```sh
PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

For clearance, this is the phase I was running, under `Build rules`.
[image: Image showing the script i've ran]

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to find two workarounds that work with this issue, the first is to symlink the program you want from `/opt/homebrew/bin` onto `/usr/local/bin` (`protoc` in my case)

```sh
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/protoc /usr/local/bin/protoc
```

The second is to add the following line to the build rule script:

```sh
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

This has the disadvantage of not working on non M1 Macs.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this the solution for now is adding the these lines to my Xcode run scripts.

```
if [[ ! $PATH =~ /opt/homebrew/bin: ]] ; then 
PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/:/opt/homebrew/sbin:${PATH}
fi
```